# LiveChart within a UserControl doesn't get drawn

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I'm using the [LiveCharts.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LiveCharts.WinForms/) package. I've placed a chart within a UserControl (called Panel). The chart looks fine in design mode. I then I have a second (parent) UserControl where I add Panel controls through code at runtime. This parent control is placed in a Form. Panels are added like this:

```
this.PanelParentControl.Controls.Add(new MyCustomerPanel());
```

When running the app, the chart is just a big black rectangle (or just doesn't show up). I've tried calling `Refresh`, `Invalidate`, `SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout` but it doesn't work. However, the DataLabels do get displayed when I move the mouse around the chart (or where it should actually be displayed).

Am I missing something? Any ideas on how to get the chart to display when it's being added at runtime?

Comment: Got any solution for this ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?